# Facebook/Python: Get a page that has all my friends without "see more" button

Tags: python, facebook

I'm trying to see my or my friend's friends. I only get a page that displays about 20 of them and it loads further when I get to the bottom. 
The problem is I want to get this HTML by Python so I need a page that has the complete list of friends, without the "see more" feature. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you done](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) answer your own question? Do you think it is possible? Why (not)?

Comment: I tried to see a list of all my friends, I think there must be a link that tells facebook to display ALL the friends in a page, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the Facebook API instead of doing this with scraping (as it seems you are trying to do).

I generally avoid parsing HTML when I can.

See documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friends